# Linked list with iterators

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, linked-list, iterator

This is my second linked list implementation for review.  I rewritten pretty much all of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55655/linked-list-implementation-correctness) and have added iterators, sentinels and The Rule of Five.

Please let me know what's wrong with it; I am still not confident in many areas.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory>

#pragma once

template <typename T>
class LinkedList;

template <typename TNode>
class LinkedListIterator
{
    friend class LinkedList<typename TNode::value_type>;
    TNode* p;
public:
    LinkedListIterator(TNode* p) : p(p) {}
    LinkedListIterator(const LinkedListIterator& other) : p(other.p) {}
    LinkedListIterator& operator=(LinkedListIterator other) { std::swap(p, other.p); return *this; }
    void operator++() { p = p->next; }
    void operator++(int) { p = p->next; }
    bool operator==(const LinkedListIterator& other) { return p == other.p; }
    bool operator!=(const LinkedListIterator& other) { return p != other.p; }
    const int& operator*() const { return p->data; }
    LinkedListIterator<TNode> operator+(int i)
    {
        LinkedListIterator<TNode> iter = *this;
        while (i-- > 0 && iter.p)
        {
            ++iter;
        }
        return iter;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Node
{
    friend class LinkedList<T>;
    friend class LinkedListIterator<Node<T>>;
    friend class LinkedListIterator<const Node<T>>;

    Node() : next(nullptr) {}
    Node(const T &data) : data(data), next(nullptr) {}
    Node<T> *next;
    T data;
public:
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    typedef Node<T> node;

    std::size_t size;
    std::unique_ptr<node> head;
    std::unique_ptr<node> tail;

    void init()
    {
        size = 0;
        head.reset(new node);
        tail.reset(new node);
        head->next = tail.get();
    }

public:
    typedef LinkedListIterator<node> iterator;
    typedef LinkedListIterator<const node> const_iterator;

    LinkedList() { init(); }

    LinkedList(const LinkedList& other)
    {
        init();
        const_iterator i = other.begin();
        while (i != other.end())
        {
            add(*i);
            i++;
        }

        head.reset(other.head.get());
        tail.reset(other.tail.get());
    }

    LinkedList(LinkedList&& other)
    {
        init();
        size = other.size;
        head = other.head;
        tail = other.tail;
        other.first = nullptr;
        other.size = 0;
    }

    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList other)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList&& other)
    {
        assert(this != &other);     
        while (head->next != tail)
            remove(begin());
        head = other.head;
        tail = other.tail;
        size = other.size;
        first = other.first;
        other.size = 0;
        other.first = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~LinkedList()
    {
        while (head->next != tail.get())
            remove(begin());
    }

    friend void swap(LinkedList& first, LinkedList& second)
    {
        std::swap(first.size, second.size);
        std::swap(first.head, second.head);
        std::swap(first.tail, second.tail);
    }

    void add(const T &value)
    {
        node *first = new node(value);
        first->next = head->next;
        head->next = first;
        size++;
    }

    void remove(iterator& removeIter)
    {
        node *last = head.get();
        iterator i = begin();

        while (i != removeIter)
        {
            last = i.p;
            ++i;
        }

        if (i != end())
        {
            last->next = i.p->next;
            size--;
            delete i.p;
        }
    }

    const int getSize() 
    { 
        return size;
    }

    iterator begin() 
    {
        return iterator(head->next);
    }

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return const_iterator(head->next);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(tail.get());
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return const_iterator(tail.get());
    }
};
```

Comment: I would recommend using (e.g.) `this->size` instead of just `size`

Comment: @MiJyn I disagree. Unnecessary prefacing of member variables with `this->` is not generally seen as good style.

Comment: @Yuushi seriously? I personally find that it makes code harder to read

Answer (score 9):

In all, this is pretty well structured code and I had no problem reading and understanding it.  Whenever another programmer can read and understand your code, it's a good sign that you're on the right track.  So what's left is mostly small points that might improve your code.  Here's what I noticed in no particular order.

### Use the appropriate `#include`s

This code uses `std::swap` which is actually defined in `<algorithm>` up to C++11, but `<utility>` in more recent versions of the standard.  You've included `<stdlib.h>` but in a C++ program that should actually be `<cstdlib>` which puts the various declarations into the `std::` namespace rather than in the global namespace.

### Use the right forms of `const`

The `LinkedList` class contains a `getSize()` function.  Right now that's declared as

```
const int getSize()    // const will be ignored for this return type
```

but I think what you really meant was this:

```
int getSize() const     // this call does not alter the underlying object
```

### Don't use variables that are not in scope

The two `move` operators of the `LinkedList` class both refer to a member data pointer named `first` but no such variable is actually declared.  The three lines in those two functions that refer to `first` should simply be deleted.

### Think about temporary object usage

The `LinkedList` class includes a number of member functions in which `remove(begin())` is called.  However, a close look shows that `begin()` returns a temporary of type `iterator`.  However, the `remove()` function takes a non-const *reference* to an `iterator` and so we have a problem.  One solution is to change `remove` to use move semantics.

Another problem is easily shown when using this common C++11 idiom to print all of the data members of the linked list:

```
for (const auto &val : mylist)
    std::cout << val << '\n';
```

The intent here is to print the values of all of the linked list values without modifying them (hence `const`) and without copying them (hence `&`).  Unfortunately this won't work with the current version of the code.  The problem is once again the use of temporary values.  In particular, this effectively calls this operator:

```
const int& operator*() const { return p->data; }
```

But `p->data` isn't necessarily an `int` so the way to fix this is:

```
typename TNode::value_type& operator*() const { return p->data; }
```

### Write member initializers in declaration order

The `Node` class has this constructor

```
Node(const T &data) : data(data), next(nullptr) {}
```

That looks fine, but in fact, `next` will be initialized *before* `data` because members are always initialized in *declaration* order and `next` is declared before `data` in this class. To avoid misleading another programmer, you should swap the order of those such that it says instead:

```
Node(const T &data) : next(nullptr), data(data) {}
```

This way the initialization actually proceeds from left to right as one might expect at first glance.

### Iterator increment operators should return a reference

The code has two increment operators, a preincrement and a postincrement:

```
void operator++() { p = p->next; }
void operator++(int) { p = p->next; }
```

However, consider the following use:

```
for (auto it = ll.begin(); it != ll.end(); )
    std::cout << *it++ << '\n';
```

This will fail because `it++` returns `void` instead of a reference to a `LinkedListIterator`.  The preincrement is easy to fix:

```
LinkedListIterator& operator++() { p = p->next; return *this; }
```

The postincrement cannot be the same thing, though, because it is required to return the value *before* the increment.  In other words, if `int i = 5;` we would expect `std::cout << ++i << '\n';` to print "6" but `std::cout << i++ << '\n';` should print "5".  So to fix the postincrement we do this:

```
LinkedListIterator operator++(int) { LinkedListIterator it(*this); p = p->next; return it; }
```

Note that this returns an actual `LinkedListIterator` *object* and not an *object reference* as with the preincrement operator.

### Consider making the iterators more general purpose

As it stands, an attempt to sort an instance of this `LinkedList` using `std::sort` will fail:

```
std::sort(ll.begin(), ll.end());
```

The problem is that `std::sort` expects to be able to check iterator traits (such as [`random_access_iterator_tag`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/)) to tell the Standard Template Library (STL) which iterators can support which algorithms.

### Use `cbegin` and `cend`

The STL uses `cbegin` and `cend` as names for the constant versions of the iterator members.  This is convenient because it allows usage such as this:

```
for (auto it = ll.cbegin(); it != ll.cend(); ++it)
    // do something with each member
```

This code can easily be modified to conform to this by simply renaming the two functions.

### Fix your copy constructors

This code will cause a seg fault:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    LinkedList<std::string> ll;
    ll.add("one");
    LinkedList<std::string> l2 = ll;
    l2.add("two");
    std::cout << "The copy\n";
    for (auto it = l2.begin(); it != l2.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    std::cout << "The original\n";
    for (auto it = ll.begin(); it != ll.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

The problem is in the copy constructor:

```
LinkedList(const LinkedList& other)
{
    init();  // head is created and points to tail
    const_iterator i = other.begin();
    while (i != other.end())
    {
        add(*i);   // head now points to last added node
        i++;
    }

    head.reset(other.head.get());  // head now points to other's first node!
    tail.reset(other.tail.get());
}
```

Clearly those last two lines are not helpful, and we can also clean up the rest:

```
LinkedList(const LinkedList& other)
{
    init();  
    for (auto i = other.cbegin(); i != other.cend(); ++i)
        add(*i); 
}
```

Unfortunately, the move constructor has a similar problem, but I'll leave it to you to fix.  Generally speaking, you may want to instrument your code and make sure that you have exercised all member functions, ideally with a few different kinds of data (I tend to use `std::complex` and `std::string` as convenient and complete classes for testing container templates).

Comment: I'm confused by your advice about `operator*() const`, which you suggest should return a copy of the value; you say that `return p->data;` creates a temporary of some sort. It would be unusual to return a copy here, and undesirable whenever `T` is large. The lifetime of `p->data` shouldn't be an issue; it is normal for iterators to be invalidated (i.e. it is undefined behavior to use them) when e.g. the collection they iterate over is destroyed.

Comment: @ruds: rereading what I wrote there, I'm inclined to agree with you.  There are other problems with the code but this isn't one of them.  I have amended my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- `operator!=` **must** be defined as a negation of `operator==`.
- A (non-random-access) forward iterator shall not define an `operator+`. `std::advance` does the job.
- I don't think that `operator++` can be `void`.

Otherwise looks very compliant.

PS: did you try it against STL's `find`, `copy` and friends and family?

Comment: [citation needed] for the requirement that `operator !=` be implemented as a negation of `operator==`.

Comment: I can't quote a video here, sorry. Alex Stepanov goes deep on the topic in his lectures at https://www.youtube.com/user/A9Videos/videos

Comment: I find it hard to believe that a good reason could not be stated briefly enough to fit here, but could you at least tell us which video?

Comment: @Beta Briefly: a "not equal" relation _is_ a negation of an "equal" relation, by definition. An attempt to define it in any other way is wrong. A very interesting discussion is in Programming Conversations 11 (part 2 specifically). However I highly recommend all of them.

Comment: I agree that one should be defined as the negation of the other (for at least three reasons), and I tend to write op== first and then define op!= in terms of it, as a matter of style, but why "**must**" it be that way? Apart from awkwardness, what's wrong with defining op!= first and then negating it to get op==?

Comment: You are asking a very valid question. A short answer is that equality is fundamental. A long answer would explain what _fundamental_ really means, and it is a topic for a very long conversation. Again, Stepanov addresses it constantly, and explains it better than I'd ever hope to.

Comment: only the *semantics* of `a!=b` should be `!(a==b)`, not the actual implementation. You could equally define `a==b` as `!(a!=b)`

Comment: There's nothing that _forbids_ `operator+()` - it's merely not required (and it won't get used by generic algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

Other answers got most things, I am just adding what they missed.

---

**1) Avoid having same names of member variables and method arguments**

`LinkedListIterator(TNode* p) : p(p) {}` --- Avoid having same names of member variables and method arguments, since if you need to use it in the constructor, you may be surprised of what gets used.

For example :

```
LinkedListIterator(TNode* p) : p(p) {
  ++ p; // ops method argument modified
}
```

**2) Avoid having init functions**

The constructors are for the class initialization, therefore try to avoid having such functions. As other answers showed, you even made it wrong.

If you need to initialize common things in several constructors, you can use [this way of initializing common member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662441/c11-allows-in-class-initialization-of-non-static-and-non-const-members-what-c).

**3) Try to avoid using the `friend` keyword**

The fact that you used the `friend` keyword in so many places, indicates that the coupling of your classes is high, meaning you didn't do your design properly.

Comment: Good point on the `init` function, but the link you provide is not a good one.  In fact, the problem with the existing `init` is that it causes the constructor to invoke `head.reset()` and `tail.reset()` before `head` or `tail` are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

## Provide the other iterator-returning methods.

Right now, the code provides const and mutable versions of `begin()` and `end()`.  To act like the standard containers, we should also provide the rest (boilerplate):

```
using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin(); }
const_iterator cend() const { return end(); }


reverse_iterator rbegin() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
reverse_iterator rend() { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end()); }

const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end()); }

const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return rbegin(); }
const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return rend(); }
```

## Missing iterator method

It's easily overlooked, but required by `InputIterator` concept:

```
const auto* operator->() const { return &p->data; }
auto* operator->() { return &p->data; }
```

(I note in passing that `operator*()` has been declared with the wrong return type - that needs to be fixed).